# Weight of malt when wet

Tags: malt

Is there a known weight of malts/grain when wet?

Say I have 10kg of malt when dry, what is that weight when wet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on the composition of your grains, as the absorption is different between different grains.

The normal absorption is somewhere between  .1 and .2 gallons of water absorbed per pound of grain. In my experience it tends to be closer to the lower end of this spectrum.

So with some maths

10kg = ~22 LBs

Loss In Gallons:  2.2gal (min @ .1 gal) - 4.4gal (max @ .2 gal)

Absorption in KG where 1 gallon of water weighs ~  3.78 kg

8.3kg - 16.6kg

So, your wet grain will likely weigh somewhere between
18.3kg - 26.6kg  although I think it'll be closer to the 18kg range.

Apologies for odd back-and-forth conversions here. Most of my brewing knowledge lives in the odd U.S. system of weights and measure.

Comment: Presumably, the wet grain weight is most interesting after you have mashed. I think your answer could be improved if you include the loss in weight of the grain in the mash, as the bulk of the sugars that are produced by mashing will dissolve in the water and be deducted from the wet grain weight.

Comment: Sure, although that I do not know off hand. Likely hard to answer without a lot of specific information about the diastatics of the grist. Although I imagine the weight difference from that is sort of arbitrary unless you're calculating this for a specific industrial use case for an amount of grain far beyond 10kg.

Answer (score 1):

We always assume weight wet is 1.8 * dry weight, which is inline with Rob's estimeates.